# Which folders/files in drupal 6 need not executive permission?

Tags: security, files

In order to tighten security of D6 against malicious XSS file uploads, I am wondering what files and folders can have go-x permission where the group is webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All folders need `+x` perhaps you're referring to `+w` ? In which case, only the files folder e.g in `/sites/default/files` needs to be `+w` by the webserver. All other folders can be owned and writeable by root only.

Here's some find commands to recursively chmod the file/folder permissions correctly

```
;Change all directories to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x):
find /var/www/mysite -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

;Change all files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):
find /var/www/mysite -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

;Change ownership of files directory and files to webserver user, e.g www-data
chown -R www-data:www-data sites/default/files
```

Update: example nginx conf to disallow .php file access in the files directory:

```
# Do not attempt to serve php files within sites/default/files
location ~* ^/sites/default/files/.*\.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: David, the problem that I'm struggling is that, when I allow execution on files, people upload malicious images and do session hijacking. When I remove execution permission form folders the can not do that but then no uploaded images is displayed. Any suggestions to avoid this? Thanks

Comment: You can't remove +x from folders and +x shouldn't be on most files in the first place. Images should only by jpg,png etc.. not executable files. Files in the files dir can't be executed either if using the standard core .htaccess file handler in there

Comment: well I'm using nginx in front of php-fpm so .htaccess can not help.

Comment: If nginx you should add a rule to deny executable file access in the files dir, e.g .php returns 404

Comment: @alfish example nginx conf to deny .php execution in files directory added.

Comment: thanks man. Does this rule stop php files disguised as .jpg (I have seen many like badfile.php.jpg) ? What about binary files?

Comment: Those files shouldn't execute, but could be excluded in a similar way, e.g `location ~* ^/sites/default/files/.*(\.php|\.php\.*)$ {}`

Comment: Also make sure you have `try_files $uri =404;` under your `location ~ \.php$` fpm settings ([source](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/))

Comment: Yes, that will prevent trying to execute image.jpg as a php script if image.jpg.php is requested (and it doesn't exist) see also: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls > Passing Uncontrolled Requests to PHP

Comment: Thanks guys. Apparently even the official configuration suggestions of nginx have had flaws: https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/